# changing multiple piped values in a variable dynamically in C possible?

Tags: c, variables, pipe, definition

I'm trying to think of a way I can change active slot definitions in an SAI
audio definition block written in C.

```
#define ACTIVE_TDM_SLOTS 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
```

the numbers are uint32_t values used in this struct that when present activate TDM audio slots on a micro.

```
typedef struct{ 
  uint32_t FirstBitOffset;                            
  uint32_t SlotSize;        
  uint32_t SlotNumber;                           
  uint32_t SlotActive;  
}SAI_SlotInitTypeDef;
```

I'm trying to think of a way to dynamically change the makeup of ACTIVE_TDM_SLOTS depending on what channels need to be active. 
256 possible combinations of active channels. 
I can init and deInit the hardware slots to change the config of active slots.

I'm assuming #define `#ifdef/#endef` are all pre-processor so I need to use variables somehow?

I could make a string from desired active channels for ACTIVE_TDM_SLOTS but how to load that into the variable ? can I use a group of char *var and join them together into the variable ?

I am not entirely sure how the pipes are working with the definition in the 1st place! perhaps its just not possible to load this into a variable?

My other solution would be filter the active slot data from DMA as it stream in but it seams more sensible to activate or de-activate the required slots?

Happy to upload more code if its useful.

Comment: where is this being used? Looks like a bitwise or, the result would be `15`? Don't know *why* it would make sense though...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `#define ACTIVE_TDM_SLOTS ( (1u<<0) | (1u<<1) | (1u<<2)...`? Otherwise I have no idea what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

ok , I think I missed one obvious thing.

SAI_SLOT_NOTACTIVE 0;

I just assign 0 to | uint32_t variables | that are not active. 
I was thinking I had to remove the slot in the slotActive list!

I'll post back if this works in case this confuses anyone else trying
to dynamically change SAI TDM audio slot config on ARM STM32xxx

original definition

```
     /* SAI_Block_Slot_Active SAI Block Slot Active */
        #define SAI_SLOT_NOTACTIVE           ((uint32_t)0x00000000U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_0             ((uint32_t)0x00000001U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_1             ((uint32_t)0x00000002U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_2             ((uint32_t)0x00000004U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_3             ((uint32_t)0x00000008U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_4             ((uint32_t)0x00000010U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_5             ((uint32_t)0x00000020U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_6             ((uint32_t)0x00000040U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_7             ((uint32_t)0x00000080U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_8             ((uint32_t)0x00000100U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_9             ((uint32_t)0x00000200U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_10            ((uint32_t)0x00000400U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_11            ((uint32_t)0x00000800U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_12            ((uint32_t)0x00001000U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_13            ((uint32_t)0x00002000U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_14            ((uint32_t)0x00004000U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_15            ((uint32_t)0x00008000U)
        #define SAI_SLOTACTIVE_ALL           ((uint32_t)0x0000FFFFU)
```

example with chanel 1 2 3 4 routed to the 1st 4 record slots and
channel 5 6 7 8 disabled

channel number change to slot count used

```
 /* TDM record slot assign to channel or deactivate any TDMx value 0 to disable slot */ 
        uint32_t TDM1 = SAI_SLOTACTIVE_0; 
        uint32_t TDM2 = SAI_SLOTACTIVE_1;
        uint32_t TDM3 = SAI_SLOTACTIVE_2;
        uint32_t TDM4 = SAI_SLOTACTIVE_3;
        uint32_t TDM5 = SAI_SLOT_NOTACTIVE;
        uint32_t TDM6 = SAI_SLOT_NOTACTIVE;
        uint32_t TDM7 = SAI_SLOT_NOTACTIVE;
        uint32_t TDM8 = SAI_SLOT_NOTACTIVE;

haudio_out_sai.SlotInit.SlotActive = TDM1 | TDM2 | TDM3 | TDM4 | TDM5 | TDM6 | TDM7 | TDM8;

haudio_out_sai.SlotInit.SlotNumber = 4;
```